# How to set encoding off windows 10 to UTF-8?

Tags: windows, encoding, utf-8

I have some issues when i try to visualize data using SQL-Navigator,

After a long research i discovered that the problem is related to the encoding of windows.

How to set encoding of windows 10 to UTF-8 (65001)?

Comment: Windows has no specific encoding. Supports all of them, even side by side in one application - thus it is up to the application itself. The only place where this could be a problem is a console application, there you can use `chcp` command or pass codepage argument to `cmd`.

Comment: How can i change the encoding of SQL-Navigator ?

Comment: Ask thir support...